# White noise through audio jack

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, audio, ubuntu, sonic-pi

I have been using Sonic Pi recently and have been annoyed by a persistent stream of white noise. This has happened on both Raspbian and Ubuntu MATE 16.04 for Raspberry Pi, using SENNHEISER MX356s. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: There have been a lot of observations made here that the Pi's audio, particularly through the 3.5mm jack, is not great, and subject to various kinds of interference and noise.

Comment: I'm using a PiCamera and a Button on GPIO 21

Comment: I think it applies regardless of what you have connected.  It's just a crappy audio system that's not properly isolated.  If someone asked me, "Is this a good thing to buy if I want to use it primary to play music?", I'd say no.

Answer (score 6):

Per the comments below the question, the Pi's 3.5mm audio output is not a good output. I try to avoid it where possible. I have yet to see a convincing writeup of any approaches which would eliminate the noise from the analogue jack sufficiently for it to be used for enjoying music.

Your options for usable audio are:

- An HDMI to analogue converter with analogue output jack such as [this one by Tendak](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tendak-Gold-Plated-Converter-Adapter-Projector/dp/B00VTJVJ3S/ref=sr_1_21?ie=UTF8&qid=1491419158&sr=8-21&keywords=tendak+hdmi)
- An i2s based audio card such as the [HiFiBerry](https://www.hifiberry.com/) or [Pi-DAC+](http://iqaudio.co.uk/audio/8-pi-dac-0712411999643.html)
- A USB soundcard such as [this one from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1475)

I've tested a few variations on each of these approaches, and they all seem to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

The question is a bit old, but nevertheless: Add

```
audio_pwm_mode=2
```

to /boot/config.txt

(Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=136445, worked with my pi)

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: tried it, didnt work.

Comment: No difference at all on a Pi 3 B+
Presumably this is caused by poor grounding. eg there is no grounding on the pi.

Comment: Didn't make any difference for me either.  Is there any way to ground the pi?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the USB connector from adapter to RPI USB port. The 50Hz sound disappeared. This works for 5V powered audio. Some countries use 60Hz power supply.

Comment: What USB connector?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the speaker's USB power cable from the Pi's USB port to an external power brick worked for me